# Can't connect to custom hornet node using nodejs clientbuilder

Tags: javascript, hornet, aws

Have a hornet node set up on AWS, able to access the dashboard and interact with the REST API just fine. However when trying to build a connection to it using nodejs @iota/client ClientBuilder cannot connect to it.

```
async function run() {
    // this doesn't work
    const client = new ClientBuilder().node('https://<my-node-ip>:443').build();
    // this works
    const client = new ClientBuilder().node('https://api.lb-0.h.chrysalis-devnet.iota.cafe').build();

    client.getInfo().then(console.log).catch(console.error)

    const index = "testIndex";
    const data = `This message was sent at: ${new Date()}`

    try{
        const message = await client.message()
         .index(index)
         .data(data)
         .submit();
        console.log(message);
        console.log(message.messageId);
        console.log(data);
        return message.messageId.toString();
    }

    catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        throw Error("Not able to send message to tangle")
    }
}

run()
    .then(() => console.log("Done"))
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Throws an error:

```
[Error: ClientTask error: Client(NodeError("Couldn't get a result from any node"))]
[Error: ClientTask error: Client(NodeError("Couldn't get a result from any node"))]
Error: Not able to send message to tangle
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you address the issue?